# Pulling background images from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, background-image

this is a real 'noob' question, but I'm struggling with javascript.  I want the background image to change for each day of the week.  I think I have the date function implemented correctly.  I have a full URL for each of 7 images placed in an array.  I have a function that works via the buttons in the body.  I think I am calling up the array elements wrong to pass them to the changeImage function.  If I replace the array reference (piclnk[wkdy]) with a full URL, it works.  Of course, I want it to change each day.  Probably a simple answer, but I haven't found it yet.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Strict//EN">

<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function changeImage(newImage)
{
 elem = document.getElementById("mainpage");
 elem.style.backgroundImage = newImage;
}
</script>

</head>
<body id="mainpage" style="background-color:aqua">
<script type="text/javascript">
var piclnk = new Array();
var now = new Date();
var wkdy = now.getDay();
piclnk[0]='http://johndoc1.smugmug.com/2012Pictures/Beach/Mom-and-Brian-Visit-Avalon/i-  3Mp7SqD/0/X3/Moms-Visit-Beach-Busch14-X3.jpg';
piclnk[1]='http://johndoc1.smugmug.com/2012Pictures/Beach/Mom-and-Brian-Visit-Avalon/i-NpbsQVZ/0/X3/Moms-Visit-Phillies02-X3.jpg';
piclnk[2]='http://johndoc1.smugmug.com/2011Pictures/Beach/Brian-rests-a-shore-house/i-KtdDb9z/0/X3/Brian-beach-Frescos-007-X3.jpg';
piclnk[3]='http://johndoc1.smugmug.com/2012Pictures/Beach/Mom-and-Brian-Visit-Avalon/i-6FBTfLn/0/X3/Moms-Visit-Ed-Frescos03-X3.jpg';
piclnk[4]='http://johndoc1.smugmug.com/2011Pictures/Events/John-Cecilia-Wedding-Day/i-2D44Xrj/0/X3/John-and-Cecilia-wedding-068-X3.jpg';
piclnk[5]='https://sphotos-a.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-snc6/248107_3426722028174_1990858472_n.jpg';
piclnk[6]='http://johndoc1.smugmug.com/2002-pictures/Birthdays/Eileens-40th-at-Hershey/mom-michael-pippi/226530953_ULboq-X3.jpg';
var lnk = document.createElement('link');
lnk.type='text/css';
lnk.href=piclnk[wkdy];
lnk.rel='stylesheet';
changeImage('url(piclnk[wkdy])');
</script>
<button onclick="changeImage('url(http://johndoc1.smugmug.com/2012Pictures/Beach/Mom-and-Brian-Visit-Avalon/i-DNLjwPs/0/XL/Moms%20Visit%20Porch%2002-XL.jpg)')">Mom Celeste Julia</button><br>
<button onclick="changeImage('url(http://johndoc1.smugmug.com/2012Pictures/Beach/Mom-and-Brian-Visit-Avalon/i-sd3Cp9b/0/XL/Moms%20Visit%20Ed%20Frescos06-XL.jpg)')">Woltemates</button><br>
<button onclick="changeImage('url(http://johndoc1.smugmug.com/2011Pictures/Events/John-Cecilia-Wedding-Day/i-2D44Xrj/0/X3/John-and-Cecilia-wedding-068-X3.jpg)')">Eileen / Hilda</button><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the text `'url(piclnk[wkdy])'` to the `changeImage()` function - change it as follows, and it should start working:

```
changeImage('url(' + piclnk[wkdy] + ')');
```

Also, just so you know, a nicer way to build the array would be:

```
var piclnk = [
    'http://first/image.jpg',
    'http://second/image.jpg',
    'etc'
];
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, Kelvin!  It works just as I want it to work.  What's more, I see the mistake I was making.  Thanks also for the tip on arrays!

Answer (score 1):

Can I suggest adding the url string inside the change function? As such:

```
function changeImage(newImage) {
    document.getElementById('mainpage').style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + newImage + ')';
}
```

Now you can use either:

```
changeImage(piclnk[wkdy]);
```

Or:

```
<button onclick="changeImage('http://johndoc1.smugmug.com/2012Pictures/Beach/Mom-and-Brian-Visit-Avalon/i-DNLjwPs/0/XL/Moms%20Visit%20Porch%2002-XL.jpg')">Mom Celeste Julia</button><br>
```

Without needing to add the url string each time.

**EDIT:**

When prettifying the code it could look like so:

```
function changeImage(newImage) {
    document.getElementById('mainpage').style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + newImage + ')';
}

var picUrls = [
    'http://johndoc1.smugmug.com/2012Pictures/Beach/Mom-and-Brian-Visit-Avalon/i-3Mp7SqD/0/X3/Moms-Visit-Beach-Busch14-X3.jpg',
    'http://johndoc1.smugmug.com/2012Pictures/Beach/Mom-and-Brian-Visit-Avalon/i-NpbsQVZ/0/X3/Moms-Visit-Phillies02-X3.jpg',
    'http://johndoc1.smugmug.com/2011Pictures/Beach/Brian-rests-a-shore-house/i-KtdDb9z/0/X3/Brian-beach-Frescos-007-X3.jpg',
    'http://johndoc1.smugmug.com/2012Pictures/Beach/Mom-and-Brian-Visit-Avalon/i-6FBTfLn/0/X3/Moms-Visit-Ed-Frescos03-X3.jpg',
    'http://johndoc1.smugmug.com/2011Pictures/Events/John-Cecilia-Wedding-Day/i-2D44Xrj/0/X3/John-and-Cecilia-wedding-068-X3.jpg',
    'https://sphotos-a.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-snc6/248107_3426722028174_1990858472_n.jpg',
    'http://johndoc1.smugmug.com/2002-pictures/Birthdays/Eileens-40th-at-Hershey/mom-michael-pippi/226530953_ULboq-X3.jpg'
], weekDay = (new Date()).getDay();

changeImage(picUrls[weekDay]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have it working with the other response, but I will try this approach.  It looks like it might clean up the code.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert the array item into the string (the way you have it now, it's just a literal string, that doesn't refer to your array at all):

```
changeImage('url(' + piclnk[wkdy] + ')');
```